# Node.js Handle session with database

Tags: node.js, database, session, cookies, session-cookies

Basically I have a Node.js web application which uses the express-session module to handle sessions.

It works perfectly but with 1 expectation which ruins this option for me. If the Server crashes or I deploy a new release, the sessions get wiped out complety and thats unacceptable for me. Also its bad that I cant share the session between my main and my backup server.

So my goal is to handle the session via a external cloud database, just think of it as a "casual mysql database".

But here is the point were I just get confused on how to do that. I can assign unique ids to the sessions and depending on those load the resources from the database, but how can I re-recognize the users if these sessions get wiped away?

I am lacking alot of knowledge about sessions, but since this is quite a critical topic for me I post a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of those stores (or write your own) :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores

I'm using the connect mongo to store sessions in my mongo DB, code looks like this (app.js) :

```
import session from 'express-session';
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
...
...
    api.use(session({
        secret: global.config.secrets.session,
        saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
        resave: false, //don't save session if unmodified
        store: new MongoStore({
            mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
            touchAfter: 24 * 3600 // time period in seconds
        })
    }));
```